# Why is the accuracy of CNN model changing every time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I got this error, “Allocation of 73138176 exceeds 10% of system memory”, when I run image classification codes via CNN. I used different solutions to solve my problem. However, it changed the model accuracy in each testing.

Model accuracy here was **0.6761**.

```
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=9, validation_split=0.3)
```

Then, when I lowered batch_size to **2**, the accuracy here increased to **0.8451**. Also, it did not give any errors related to the allocation problem.

```
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=2, epochs=9, validation_split=0.3)
```

Then, I was also curious about a code *which also solved the allocation problem*. However, this time, Model accuracy here was **0.7183**. The code is;

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=9, validation_split=0.3)
```

My question is, which code do you actually suggest that I should follow? Also, could you please brighten me why the accuracy changes each time?

Thank you for every help and suggestion.

Comment: It really is impossible to answer this without information about the dataset and model architecture. Model training times can vary a lot between runs and comparing accuracy for a certain number of epochs isn't a good idea. You should follow the accuracy/validation accuracy curve(or the loss curve) e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/boKiX.png . Train your model once again using the same parameters and you might see very different results.
TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL is just a debugger flag and should never affect training.

Comment: @NiteyaShah Thank you very much. I took the accuracy/validation graph via TensorBoard. However, IN EACH RUN, the values in accuracy also change. I think you are right to train model again.

Comment: I am using the method @sentdex shared on YouTube. He uses; -->import random --> random.shuffle(training_data). Do you think this is because we get training_data randomly?

Comment: As was mentioned, raising the log level doesn't fix the problem, it just removes the message. It's not an error, more like a warning that memory use is getting very high. The only ways to fix this are to reduce memory usage (e.g. reducing the batch size), or get more memory.

Comment: No it has nothing to do with randomising the dataset. It is rather a inherent property of NNs and there is nothing wrong with this. Just train your model for more epochs and you should get all runs to nearly the same accuracy.

Comment: @NiteyaShah it does have to do with randomizing the dataset assuming tensorflow default settings; but even if you fix the order in which the dataset is visited, there is also the initialization of the weights. Depending on the details of the problem domain, you may or may not get anywhere close to repeatable results.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn thank you very much for the explanation. are there any suggestions that you may put into this issue? or maybe some approaches that you have adapted to your codes when you encounter this as well.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn yeah, I did assume that the weights are randomly initialized and that was the inherent property that I alluded to earlier. Randomizing 2 conditions is pointless in this case as long as 1 is sufficiently random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want exactly repeatable training results, you need to eliminate all sources of randomness. For a typical model training, the main sources are in 1: your dataset; randomization of the test/train split, or randomization of the order in which batches are generated. And 2: the model initialization; if you want to train the same model every time, you need to start with the same initial parameters every time. How you ensure that you get 'the same random numbers' with every training run varies by framework; and it was unreasonably painful last time I tried years ago in TF; but it can be done and google should know how to do if you search for fixing the random seed in TF.

However, fixing the random seed may not be what you are interested in; for doing repeatable experiments, it's what you want. But as far as the production qualities of your model are concerned, thats a different matter. If you find that the eventual model you end up with, behaves rather different depending on the seed (and many problems will intrinsically have this property, where multiple 'equally valid' but rather different interpretations exist), training an ensemble of such models, with a different random seed each, is a useful thing to do; in this way you can gain an explicit awareness of the amount of 'room for interpretation' that you model and dataset leaves open.